# HMD suggestions for usage with ROS software

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm searching for an HMD (head-mounted display) to use for stereoscopic vision and pan&tilt camera control using IMU readings.

As such, the requirements are:

- Good resolution and stereocopic view;
- Compatibility with ubuntu;
- IMU incorporated.

Also, if you have any experience with some HMD and you use ROS, can you point how you use sterescopic view from 2 different image sources in ROS? There are many methods and I'd like to know which ones you use.

Thank you in advance,

Filipe Jesus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48852/hmd-suggestions-for-usage-with-ros-software./) by [Filipe Jesus](https://answers.ros.org/users/1348/filipe-jesus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-11-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might find this announcement of Occulus Rift support for rviz interesting. http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Oculus-Rift-Integration-in-RViz-td4020193.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0